# When i add the form tag the output changes

Tags: asp.net, html, layout

i face a very strange problem (at least for me) ,i got the html layout of a web page from the designer and it is exactly the same HTML of the photoshop design..when i add the HTML tags to my ASP.Net website and add the `<form runat="server"> </form>` tag after the body tag..some of the divs in the footer appear differently..

here is a screenshot of how the footer should be

[image]

and here is how it appears now

[image]

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there are some CSS rules applied to the `<form>` element which is messing up the layout.  If you can post a url to a sample page then we could tell you which rule/properties are causing this.

Comment: When i uploaded the page to the web server..it works fine as it is supposed to be...but on my computer it appears different!?